# XSLT: how to add conditions (with xsl:if) based on element attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, uml, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I want to create different elements based on their attributes. This is **XML input:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1">
    <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
    <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">
        <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_9E00FA41_6F28_4e47_9AE6_2A04EE92CDBB" name="aktivityD" visibility="public">
            <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="EAID_AC000001_6F28_4e47_9AE6_2A04EE92CDBB" name="EA_Activity1" visibility="public">
                <node xmi:type="uml:ActivityFinalNode" xmi:id="EAID_6550597C_95E6_4d78_82C8_1E3DF3916946" name="ActivityFinal" visibility="public">
                    <incoming xmi:idref="EAID_CEB43B7F_ED15_4f03_8D9B_8EF054BD458D"/>
                </node>
                <node xmi:type="uml:InitialNode" xmi:id="EAID_1EE374C2_0853_4379_A09C_1586F1F70618" name="ActivityInitial" visibility="public">
                    <outgoing xmi:idref="EAID_A7A0C176_5CCC_4bf2_AED2_AEB05FB741AF"/>
                </node>
                <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="EAID_A7A0C176_5CCC_4bf2_AED2_AEB05FB741AF" visibility="public" source="EAID_1EE374C2_0853_4379_A09C_1586F1F70618" target="EAID_6057002D_AC33_4eee_9FF9_9A7F17B830F6"/>
                <group xmi:type="uml:ActivityPartition" xmi:id="EAID_D88F2D66_C7A9_447f_8C87_2D28E2E3906F" name="Partition_1" visibility="public">
                    <node xmi:idref="EAID_6057002D_AC33_4eee_9FF9_9A7F17B830F6"/>
                </group>
                <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Activity" xmi:id="EAID_6057002D_AC33_4eee_9FF9_9A7F17B830F6" name="Activity1" visibility="public" isReadOnly="false" isSingleExecution="false"/>
                <edge xmi:type="uml:ControlFlow" xmi:id="EAID_CEB43B7F_ED15_4f03_8D9B_8EF054BD458D" visibility="public" source="EAID_6057002D_AC33_4eee_9FF9_9A7F17B830F6" target="EAID_6550597C_95E6_4d78_82C8_1E3DF3916946"/>
            </packagedElement>
        </packagedElement>
    </uml:Model>
</xmi:XMI>
```

I use this **XSLT:**

```
...
<xsl:template name="model"  match="uml:Model">
    <xsl:element name="uml:Model">
        <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">
          <xsl:value-of select="@xmi:type"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="visibility">
          <xsl:value-of select="@visibility" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="packagedElement[@xmi:type='uml:Package']">
    <xsl:element name="packagedElement">
        <xsl:attribute name="xmi:type">uml:Package</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="xmi:id">
            <xsl:value-of select="$PackID"></xsl:value-of>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">sequenceD</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="visibility">public</xsl:attribute> 
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="packagedElement[@xml:type='uml:Activity']">
    <xsl:element name="packagedElement">
        <xsl:attribute name ="xmi:type">uml:Collaboration</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name ="xmi:id">
             <xsl:value-of select="@xmi:id"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name ="name">EA_Collaboration1</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name ="visibility">public</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
...
```

I want to know how can I add some conditions to XSLT for these cases:

- if attribute (in input xml) xmi:type is "uml:Package" create that element (in xslt as second template and with those attributes)
- if attribute (in input xml) xmi:type is "uml:Activity" create element which will be under first packagedElement, it will be also  packagedElement but will have different attributes

For now this is **output XML**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1"
         xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1"
         xmi:version="2.1">
   <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
   <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">
      <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package"
                       xmi:id="EAPK_1234567"
                       name="sequenceD"
                       visibility="public"/>
   </uml:Model>
</xmi:XMI>
```

I also don´t know how to format text to one row in output XML. 
For any help: Thank you!

This is output XML what I want to create:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="2.1" xmlns:uml="http://schema.omg.org/spec/UML/2.1" xmlns:xmi="http://schema.omg.org/spec/XMI/2.1">
    <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
    <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model" visibility="public">
        <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_5947BE3D_D2DE_4dc8_A0C0_A9AC446264DA" name="sequenceD" visibility="public">
            <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Collaboration" xmi:id="EAID_CB000000_E3D_D2DE_4dc8_A0C0_A9AC446264D" name="EA_Collaboration1" visibility="public">
                <ownedBehavior xmi:type="uml:Interaction" xmi:id="EAID_IN000000_E3D_D2DE_4dc8_A0C0_A9AC446264D" name="EA_Interaction1" visibility="public">
                    <lifeline xmi:type="uml:Lifeline" xmi:id="EAID_086AF560_4699_47a6_9E42_508896EE53D0" name="Partition_1" visibility="public" represents="EAID_AT000000_4699_47a6_9E42_508896EE53D0"/>
                    <lifeline xmi:type="uml:Lifeline" xmi:id="EAID_89C15D36_76EF_42c8_8267_27793BA745F0" name="Partition_2" visibility="public" represents="EAID_AT000000_76EF_42c8_8267_27793BA745F0"/>
                    <fragment xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" xmi:id="EAID_FR000000_4699_47a6_9E42_508896EE53D0" covered="EAID_086AF560_4699_47a6_9E42_508896EE53D0"/>
                    <fragment xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" xmi:id="EAID_FR000001_4699_47a6_9E42_508896EE53D0" covered="EAID_086AF560_4699_47a6_9E42_508896EE53D0"/>
                    <fragment xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" xmi:id="EAID_FR000000_76EF_42c8_8267_27793BA745F0" covered="EAID_89C15D36_76EF_42c8_8267_27793BA745F0"/>
                    <fragment xmi:type="uml:OccurrenceSpecification" xmi:id="EAID_FR000001_76EF_42c8_8267_27793BA745F0" covered="EAID_89C15D36_76EF_42c8_8267_27793BA745F0"/> 
                    <message xmi:type="uml:Message" xmi:id="EAID_FB6F7794_17CF_42af_870B_4BE2E8CCA386" name="Activity1" messageKind="found" messageSort="synchCall" receiveEvent="EAID_FR000000_4699_47a6_9E42_508896EE53D0"/>
                    <message xmi:type="uml:Message" xmi:id="EAID_F92A2B3B_C28E_43d5_BDDB_78AD13663BF1" name="Activity2" messageKind="complete" messageSort="synchCall" sendEvent="EAID_FR000001_4699_47a6_9E42_508896EE53D0" receiveEvent="EAID_FR000000_76EF_42c8_8267_27793BA745F0"/>
                    <message xmi:type="uml:Message" xmi:id="EAID_BCF881AC_1967_429c_85C3_75487A34866A" messageKind="lost" messageSort="synchCall" sendEvent="EAID_FR000001_76EF_42c8_8267_27793BA745F0"/>
                </ownedBehavior>
                <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="EAID_AT000000_4699_47a6_9E42_508896EE53D0"/>
                <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="EAID_AT000000_76EF_42c8_8267_27793BA745F0"/>
            </packagedElement>
            <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="EAID_B0D14618_9DE7_43fa_989F_36F68263530A" name="ActivityFinal" visibility="public"/>
            <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="EAID_964B5D05_11B6_4ea1_86CD_391C3A60716C" name="ActivityInitial" visibility="public"/>
        </packagedElement>
    </uml:Model>
</xmi:XMI>
```

Comment: What does your desired output XML look like?

Comment: @zx485 I added output excel what I want to create, but there is one extra lifeline (partition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using templates with matches that take into account the `xmi:type` attribute's value.

```
<xsl:template name="model" match="uml:Model">
  <xsl:element ... >
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="packagedElement[@xmi:type='uml:Package']">
  <xsl:element ... >
    ...
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="packagedElement[@xmi:type='uml:Activity']">
  <xsl:element ... >
    ...
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

...

Comment: So should I call its with <xsl:apply-templates select="packagedElement[@xml:type='uml:Activity']"/>

Comment: you can do, however in the context of the first template there is only so many things that can be matched next (i.e. another packagedElement within the packageElement that is the current context of the first template). Hence you can keep it open or close it in like you suggest

Comment: it is not working. I don´t know where can be a mistake, but it writes only first element.

Comment: you mean it's only writing model, or only writing model and the first level packagedElement? Could you post an update w. what your xsl looks like currently?

Comment: only model and the first level packagedElement. There is how it looks like behind "For now this is output XML:"

Comment: I've updated the example in my answer to provide more direction. You need to call `<apply-templates />` from within the _model_ template and the _packageElement_ template for xmi:type=package.

Comment: I´ve updated XSLT based on your answer, but nothing changing. It writes only first level packagedElement. What do you think, where I made a mistake?

Comment: Difficult to tell without seeing the code first hand. If you really get stuck with the pattern templates you could try the functional approach, i.e. xsl functions and call-functions. Any chance you can post your code?

Comment: I find out where was mistake. In your answer, in the third template you write `...[@xml:type..`. but there should be `...[@xmi:type...`